# Blender CUDA can't find my GPU(MAC)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

[image]
As I was adjusting my settings I realized that my GPU is not recognized for CUDA at Cycles tab. I tried everything afterward to make it appear- went to Nvidia developers website to download CUDA toolkit(10 version as 11 is not supported on MacOs), reinstall blender, etc.. but it still does not work... Could anyone please help me here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I did. I did install CUDA but since I am using Mac OS, the newest version of CUDA (11 I guess?) does not support it... would there be absolutely no solution at all unless I change my graphics card..? I have also thought of buying some sort of external graphics card but not sure if this is the right way to go...